# Node.js Only allow asset to pass through specific webpage

Tags: node.js, express

In my current Express Node.js file , I have this bit of simple code:

```
app.get('/t/:v', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(dir + "/src/t/" + req.params.v + ".jpg");
});
```

And in my HTML:

```
<img class="nav video" src="t/{{video-1}}"></img>
```

It just sends a thumbnail file over, but I want to make sure that this file is not being viewed by the user in ***any other way*** than from that webpage, I've tried everything from cookies to session ids, none of them work how I want, and I'd like to think there's a simpler way.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you expound a bit more? What other way is the thumbnail being viewed that you wish to stop?

Comment: I do not want the image to be able to be displayed directly (i.e. /t/15), only in the index.html file.